# Showing that this function involving $L^p$-spaces is not surjective

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra on the set $X := [0,1]$ containing all countable sets and the complements of countable sets. Consider the counting measure $\mu$ defined by $\mu(\{x\}) = 1$ for all $x \in X$.

Show that the mapping $L^{\infty} \to (L^1(X))^{*}$, which takes a function $g \in L^{\infty}(X)$ to the functional
$$
\Phi_g: L^{1}(X) \to \mathbb{R}, \quad \Phi_g(f) := \int_{X}f(x)g(x) \, d\mu(x),$$
is not surjective.

Hint: Consider the function $g_0: X \to \mathbb{R}, \ g_0(x) := x$.

My approach: we want to show for our mapping $M: L^{\infty} \to (L^1(X))^{*}$ that there exists a functional $\Phi_g(f) \in (L^{1}(X))^{*}$ which has no preimage $g \in L^{\infty}$ such that $M(g) = \Phi_{g}(f)$. Now, using the given hint and plugging $g_0$ into the integral gives us
$$\Phi_{g_0}(f) = \int_{X}f(x)x\ d\mu(x)$$
For me, it is clear that this is one candidate to show that it has no preimage in $L^{\infty}$. But somehow I have difficulties to show that. And more important, I don't know how the counting measure fits into this whole picture. I have thought about possibly using the characteristic function $X_{\mathcal{A}}$ as $f(x)$ (where $\mathcal{A}$ is some countable set) and looking at
$$\Phi_{g_0}(X_{\mathcal{A}}) = \int_{X}X_{\mathcal{A}}\cdot x \ d\mu(x), $$ but I am unsure about how to proceed from there.

Can maybe anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**: What are the $\mathcal{A}$-measurable functions?

If $f: X \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable, then
for each $a \in \Bbb R$, $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is either countable or co-countable (countable complement) in $[0,1]$. Note that, if $a \neq b$ then $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is disjoint of $f^{-1}(\{b\})$. So, there is at most one $a \in \Bbb R$ such that $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is co-countable.

On the other hand, for each $a \in \Bbb R$, $f^{-1}([a,+\infty))$ is either countable or co-countable in $[0,1]$. Note that $\Bbb R = \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb Z} [n,+\infty)$. So
$$
[0,1] = f^{-1}(\Bbb R) = \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb Z}f^{-1}([n,+\infty))
$$
Since $[0,1]$ is uncountable, it can not be a countable union of countable sets. So there is $n_0 \in \Bbb Z$ such that $f^{-1}([n_0,+\infty))$ is co-countable.

Note also that $\emptyset = \bigcap_{n \in \Bbb Z} [n,+\infty)$. So
$$
\emptyset = f^{-1}(\emptyset) = \bigcap_{n \in \Bbb Z}f^{-1}([n,+\infty))
$$
Since a countable intersection of co-countable sets is co-countable and $\emptyset$ is not co-countable, we have that there is $n_1 \in \Bbb Z$ such that $f^{-1}([n_1,+\infty))$ is countable.

Let $c = \sup \{a \in \Bbb R : f^{-1}([a,+\infty)) \text{ is co-countable} \}$. It is easy to see that $c \in [n_0, n_1]$. So $c < +\infty$.

Now note that for all $m \in \Bbb N$,
$$
f^{-1}([c-\tfrac{1}{m+1}, c+ \tfrac{1}{m+1}) ) = f^{-1}([c-\tfrac{1}{m+1}, +\infty) ) \setminus f^{-1}([c+\tfrac{1}{m+1}, +\infty) )
$$
Since $c = \sup \{a \in \Bbb R : f^{-1}([a,+\infty)) \text{ is co-countable} \}$, we have that $f^{-1}([c-\tfrac{1}{m+1}, +\infty)$ is co-countable and $f^{-1}([c+\tfrac{1}{m+1}, +\infty)$ is countable, and so $f^{-1}([c-\tfrac{1}{m+1}, c+ \tfrac{1}{m+1}) )$ is co-countable.
Now, since
$$
f^{-1}(\{c\}) = f^{-1}(\bigcap_{m \in \Bbb N} [c-\tfrac{1}{m+1}, c+ \tfrac{1}{m+1})) =\bigcap_{m \in \Bbb N}f^{-1}( [c-\tfrac{1}{m+1}, c+ \tfrac{1}{m+1}))
$$
we have that $f^{-1}(\{c\})$ is co-countable (a countable intersection of co-countable set is co-countable).

So we can conclude that

> $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable if and only if it is constant on a co-countable subset of $[0,1]$.

**Second**: Let $\mu$ be the counting measure $\mu$ defined by $\mu(\{x\}) = 1$ for all $x \in X$. It is easy to see that $f \in L^1(X)$ if and only if $S_f= \{x \in X : f(x) \neq 0 \}$ is countable and
$$
\int |f| d\mu = \sum_{x \in S_f} |f(x)| < +\infty
$$

**Third**: Let $\Phi:L^1(X) \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be defined by, for all $f \in L^1(X)$
$$
\Phi(f) = \int xf(x) d\mu(x) = \sum_{x \in S_f} xf(x)
$$
It is easy to see that $\Phi$ is a linear functional. Moreover,
$$
|\Phi(f)| \leqslant \sum_{x \in S_f} |x||f(x)| \leqslant \sum_{x \in S_f} |f(x)| = \|f\|_1
$$
So $\Phi \in (L^1(X))^*$.

**Fourth**: Suppose now that there is $g \in L^{\infty}(X)$ such that, for all for all $f \in L^1(X)$, $\Phi(f) = \int f g d\mu$.

Since $g \in L^{\infty}(X)$, $g$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable, and so $g$ is constant on a co-countable subset $E$ of $X$. Let $c$ be the constant value of $g$ on $E$. Let $a, b \in E$ and $a \neq b$. Now, we have
$$
c= g(a) =  \int \chi_{\{a\}} g d\mu = \Phi(\chi_{\{a\}}) =\int x\chi_{\{a\}}(x) d\mu(x) = \sum_{x=a} x\chi_{\{a\}}(x)=a
$$
and
$$
c= g(b) =  \int \chi_{\{b\}} g d\mu = \Phi(\chi_{\{b\}}) =\int x\chi_{\{b\}}(x) d\mu(x) = \sum_{x=b} x\chi_{\{b\}}(x)=b
$$
Contradiction (because $a \neq b$). So, there is NO $g \in L^{\infty}(X)$ such that, for all for all $f \in L^1(X)$, $\Phi(f) = \int f g d\mu$. In reality, there is NO $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function $g$  such that, for all for all $f \in L^1(X)$, $\Phi(f) = \int f g d\mu$.